# Skeptics.SE Literature Reviews

Tags: discussion

As Skeptics.SE grows, there are some topics that clearly cause concern and have been richly mined with questions and answers.

While tags link many of these questions together, it can be difficult to get an overall view of what has been discussed in a topic by a flat list.

The question (with a slightly tongue-in-cheek title) provides a place for people to help out by providing an 
overview (in whatever format is most convenient) to allow people to discover  what has already been covered.

Comment: Would you like to summarize these in blog posts instead?

Answer (score 5):

### Sweeteners

There are a large number of questions about the health effects of sugar and artificial sweeteners - too many to list as related questions.

This chart provides a map. Hopefully, it will help people discover duplicate questions more easily.

```
                               Natural   |           Artificial            | In
    Claim                   Sugar   HFCS | General   Aspartame   Sucralose | Drinks
    -------------------------------------|---------------------------------|----------
    Generally Healthy       3409    3409   8107       11127                   2523
                            2077     370                                      8586
                             370    3727                                      6996
                            2351
                            4279        
    Causes Weight Gain      3409    3409   13993                              13993
                            1263                                              1263
                                                                              2523
    Causes Hyperactivity                    6485
    Causes Cancer          10935     369                            10345      6415
    Causes MS                                                                 6415
    Causes Diabetes         6284                                                 2523
                            8940                                                 8626
    Cause Tooth Decay       5399                                              6191
    Harms immune system    13990 
                            1878
    Gives a high            1435
    Contains Mercury                3254
```

#### Notes:

- Both open and closed questions are included.
- Included if the claim is mentioned in the question, or addressed in the accepted answer or a highly-voted answer.
- Some wide-ranging questions appear in multiple places.
- HFCS (High-Fructose Corn Syrup) is nominally listed as a natural sweetener, as it it generally isn't intended for inclusion when talking about artificial sweeteners.
- Cane and Brown Sugar are both included with sugar

Answer (score 5):

### Intelligence

The topic of human intelligence makes a regular appearance on Skeptics.SE - particularly what may cause or correlate with high or low intelligence.

Here is a summary:

- **General Genetics**

  - [Inheritability](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/is-iq-hereditary-if-to-what-degree)
- **Ethnicity**

  - [Asians](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6952/did-asian-countries-top-an-iq-survey-of-50-countries)

    - [Chinese](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8537/are-there-more-people-with-genius-iqs-living-in-china-than-there-are-people-tota)
  - [Ashkenazi Jews](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9927/are-ashkenazi-jews-smarter)
- **Body Features**

  - [Gender](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7093/do-men-show-greater-variance-in-the-distribution-of-their-iq-than-women)
  - [Brain Size](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/does-brain-mass-have-any-correlation-to-intelligence)
  - [Ear Size](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/are-big-ears-a-sign-of-intelligence)
  - [Eye Glasses](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8488/is-there-a-correlation-between-intelligence-and-wearing-spectacles)
  - [Hair Colour](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8419/is-hair-colour-correlated-with-intelligence), [Hair Colour](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5274/are-blondes-dumb-or-is-it-just-a-sarcastic-saying)
  - [Left handedness](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1663/are-left-handed-people-smarter-or-more-creative)
- **Life Choices**

  - [Faith](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/are-non-religious-people-smarter-than-religious-people)
  - [Family Size](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5850/intelligence-and-number-of-children)
- **Consumption**

  - [Exercise](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5620/does-moderate-exercise-improve-learning-ability)
  - [Modafinil](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/does-modafinil-make-you-smarter)
  - [LSD](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/does-lsd-provide-a-creativity-boost)
  - [Fluoridated Water](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7154/does-consuming-fluoridated-water-reduce-iq)
  - [Puzzles](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/does-solving-sudoku-puzzles-improve-your-mental-abilities)
  - [Video Games](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8233/does-playing-popular-video-games-improve-a-childs-iq)
  - [Television](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6504/does-watching-tv-make-you-stupid)
  - [Web Browser Choice](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5553/does-your-choice-of-browser-relate-to-your-iq)
  - [Google](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14590/does-constant-googling-really-make-us-stupid)
  - [Calculators](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6505/if-children-use-calculators-in-primary-school-is-their-learning-impacted)
- **Personality/Psychology**

  - [Sense of Humour](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13988/is-sense-of-humor-somehow-related-to-intelligence)
  - [Autism Spectrum](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/are-there-large-scale-studies-investigating-relationship-between-iq-and-autism-s)
  - [Psychopathy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8435/are-psychopaths-more-intelligent-than-people-in-general)
- **Over Time**

  - [Globally](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8259/is-global-iq-dropping-over-time)
  - [North America](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/are-people-getting-smarter-or-stupider-in-north-america)
  - [UK](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3093/are-exams-getting-easier-or-are-students-getting-smarter)
- **IQ Tests**

  - [Reliability](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/are-iq-tests-reliable)

#### Notes:

- Some questions make the distinction between Intelligence and IQ.
- Ethnicity, Body Features, Personality and Psychology are all strongly correlated with genetics, while Life Choices are correlated with Ethnicity, making some of the category distinctions here arbitrary.
- Some questions ask about correlation, while others ask about causation. Some are about permanent and others are about temporary effects. Most claims assert a direction of the expected effect.

Answer (score 3):

## Racism

Many questions have been asked that explore whether race-based claims (including affirmative action and distinctly racist claims) have a scientific backing. Included here are questions based on ethnicity, country, skin-colour and other factors that are strongly correlated with race.

Historically, these questions have rarely earned good answers, and are often closed, because, on examination, they are poorly constructed.

I've ignored some borderline questions (e.g. [1](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/is-china-buying-up-the-worlds-arable-land), [2](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/do-russians-drink-as-much-alcohol-as-their-stereotype-suggests), [3](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8537/are-there-more-people-with-genius-iqs-living-in-china-than-there-are-people-tota)) as not race-based.

#### Racism in general

- [Is race a scientific concept?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/399/is-race-a-discredited-scientific-concept-in-biology)
- [Is racism natural?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/is-racism-a-natural-instinct)
- [Does Evolutionary Psychology predict racism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6780/does-evolutionary-psychology-predict-that-humans-will-be-more-altruistic-to-thos)
- [Is Affirmative Action effective?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/are-reservations-affirmative-action-programs-successful-at-alleviating-financial)

#### Attributes possibly correlated to race

- [Penis Size](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2679/is-there-a-correlation-between-penis-size-and-race)
- [Body Temperature](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/do-japanese-people-have-a-lower-body-temperature-than-caucasians)
- [Jump height](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/can-black-people-on-average-jump-higher-than-white-people)
- [Intelligence](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14158/intelligence-of-different-races)
- [Intelligence](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6952/did-asian-countries-top-an-iq-survey-of-50-countries)
- [Intelligence](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8419/is-hair-colour-correlated-with-intelligence)
- [Intelligence](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5274/are-blondes-dumb-or-is-it-just-a-sarcastic-saying)
- [Intelligence](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9927/are-ashkenazi-jews-smarter)
- [Skin color](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/do-black-genes-persist-through-7-generations)

#### Racism In Political Groups and Policies

- [USA's Tea Party](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2882/are-there-credible-documented-widespread-evidence-showing-racism-or-lack-of)
- [Canadian New Democratic Party](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2882/are-there-credible-documented-widespread-evidence-showing-racism-or-lack-of)
- [USA's War on Drugs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/12258/has-the-war-on-drugs-disproportionately-affected-minority-communities)
- [USA's Voter Id Laws](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10696/are-voter-id-laws-harmful-to-minority-voters)
- [USA's Democrats](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10823/is-racial-resentment-towards-african-americans-correlated-with-democrats-support)
- [Caused the USA's sub-prime mortgage bubble](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3103/did-anti-discrimination-efforts-lead-to-the-sub-prime-mortgage-bubble)

#### Individuals and Racism

- [Colonel Sanders](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5676/was-colonel-sanders-racist)
- [Eleanor Roosevelt](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8471/did-eleanor-roosevelt-say-that-the-jews-brought-the-holocaust-on-themselves)

#### Miscellaneous

- [Pepsi](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/does-the-pepsi-brand-name-stand-for-pay-every-penny-to-save-israel)
- [Software Development](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7540/is-professional-software-development-discriminatory)
- [Terrorism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/are-most-terrorists-muslim)

Answer (score 2):

## Radiation

Many questions have been asked about radiation and radioactivity. There are many types of radiation that have been bundled together in this list.

### Danger Levels

- [Beneficial Levels](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2485/is-some-level-of-radiation-good-for-you)
- [Safe Levels](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9069/is-there-a-lower-limit-on-radiation-thats-harmless-to-humans) [closed]
- [Non-Ionizing](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14501/is-non-ionizing-radiation-known-to-cause-any-health-issues)
- [Radiation versus Radioactivity](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/is-background-radiation-a-secondary-concern-over-radioactive-particles-themselve)
- [Dangers to children of victims](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/974/do-people-exposed-to-high-levels-of-radiation-pose-any-risk-to-their-children-or)

## Radiation Sources

### Mobile/Cell Phones

- [Low Battery](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13807/does-a-cell-phone-emit-1000-times-more-radiation-when-its-battery-is-low)
- [Sperm Count/Heart Rate](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/does-the-presence-of-a-cellphone-affect-sperm-count-or-heart-rate/7230#7230)
- [GPS Apps](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16093/radiation-dangers-with-gps-navigation-cellphone-apps)
- [Affects babies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10239/can-radiation-from-wireless-phones-and-computers-harm-babies) [closed]
- [Trains](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/are-train-passengers-exposed-to-dangerous-levels-of-cell-phone-electromagnetic-r)
- [Brain Cancer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/569/do-mobile-phones-have-anything-to-do-with-brain-cancer/3834)

### Home Networking

- [Wifi](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/are-wifi-waves-harmful/1201#1201)
- [Wifi vs 3G](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/does-home-wifi-expose-you-to-less-radiation-than-using-the-3g-on-your-cell-phone)
- [Homeplug Style](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6297/is-the-electomagnetic-radiation-from-homeplug-style-networking-worse-than-from)
- [Powerline](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14708/do-powerline-network-adapters-emit-electromagnetic-radiation-when-not-paired)

### Microwaves

- [General Harm](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6192/are-microwave-ovens-harmful)
- [Direct Exposure](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/552/can-standing-in-front-of-a-microwave-oven-give-you-cancer/553)
- [Via Food](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/528/is-food-cooked-in-a-microwave-oven-harmful-for-the-health/6484)

### Other Home Devices:

- [Dirty Electricity](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8915/does-dirty-electricity-cause-cancer)
- [Dimmer Switches](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9620/do-dimmer-switches-increase-the-likelihood-of-cancer/9624#9624)
- [CFL Light Bulbs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/do-cfls-irradiate-ultraviolet-rays-in-a-harmful-intensity)
- [LCDs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/do-lcds-emit-harmful-radiation) [closed]

### Airport Scanners

- [Direct](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/356/do-airport-backscatter-machines-increase-the-risk-of-diseases/386#386)
- [Via Food](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/is-it-okay-to-eat-food-that-has-been-through-airport-x-ray-scanners/8300#8300)

### Nuclear Power Plants

#### Fukushima

- [Increased Infant Mortality](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5205/is-the-fukushima-disaster-causing-an-increase-in-infant-mortality-on-the-west-co/5208)
- [USS Ronald Reagan](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15345/could-fukushima-daiichi-cause-the-health-problems-suffered-by-the-uss-ronald-rea)
- [As bad as Chernobyl](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2069/is-japans-nuclear-disaster-on-par-with-chernobyl)
- [Destroying world](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/is-fukushima-reactor-no-4-on-the-verge-of-catastrophic-failure-that-will-destro/9523)

#### Chernobyl

- [Death count](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/have-several-hundreds-of-thousands-of-people-died-because-of-the-chernobyl-disas/2026#2026)
- [Life Expectancy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13581/is-this-graph-of-life-expectancy-pre-and-post-chernobyl-accurate/13583#13583)

#### Nuclear Power Plants in General

- [Compared to coal](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/do-coal-plants-release-more-radiation-than-nuclear-power-plants)
- [Living near](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7659/does-living-near-a-nuclear-power-plant-cause-cancer/7661#7661)

### Radiation Sources in General

- [High Energy Power](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/795/does-electromagnetic-radiation-from-high-energy-power-installations-have-negativ)
- [Organisms](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/315/do-organisms-have-electromagnetic-fields/318#318)
- [CT Scans](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16022/can-ct-scans-performed-on-a-childs-head-lower-his-or-her-intelligence/16030)
- [Tanning Beds](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7518/do-tanning-beds-cause-cancer-does-their-risk-outweigh-the-risks-of-vitamin-d-de)
- [Organic Cigarettes](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/do-organic-cigarettes-such-as-american-spirit-contain-less-radioactive-materia/5066#5066)
- [Depleted Uranium](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/do-depleted-uranium-shells-cause-birth-defects/14770#14770)
- [Vatican Radio](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6566/is-vatican-radio-causing-childhood-leukaemia)
- [Iranian satellite jamming](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16166/can-satellite-jamming-by-iranian-authorities-cause-medical-side-effects-on-the-i)
- [Nuclear Tests](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/did-nuclear-tests-on-the-marshall-islands-cause-increased-cancer-rates)

## Prevention and Cures

- [Biogard](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9466/can-the-bioguard-x-bracelet-protect-the-body-from-radiation)
- [Phone shields](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/can-products-that-claim-to-to-reduce-electromagnetic-radiation-from-mobile-phone)
- [Cacti](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/do-cacti-absorb-harmful-radiation-emitted-by-computers)
- [Surgical Masks](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/890/is-there-any-real-benefit-in-the-everyday-use-of-surgical-masks-to-protect-onese)
- [Alcohol](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15972/does-alcohol-consumption-have-an-effect-on-radiation-poisoning)
- [Potassium Iodide](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/898/is-potassium-iodide-useful-in-preventing-the-harmful-effects-of-radiation)

## Other

- [Radiation Laws](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3062/were-radio-frequency-radiation-levels-raised-to-accommodate-mobile-phones)
- [Benefits of High Frequency Coil](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10707/can-high-frequency-coil-radiation-kill-disease-e-g-lakhovskys-multiple-wave)
- [Hiroshima's effect on soil dating](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9663/does-the-radioactivity-on-hiroshimas-soil-affect-radiometric-dating/9667#9667)